# c# chart change max and min values on the x axis

Tags: c#, charts

Can someone tell me how to change the min and max values on the x axis on a C# chart?  I want to go from 0 to 13, but it goes from -1 to 14 right now.

Comment: Isn't it decided by your source data?

Comment: I thought so but I'm only going from i =0 to i< 14 so...I'm sure there is an option somewhere that turns off the extra padding but I'm pretty new to c#.

Comment: check out my answer, at the very least see what the current values of Maximum and Minimum are

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you are using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVizualisation.Charting` you can set the Axis range by manipulating the chart's `ChartAreas` property. So something like

```
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 13;
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```

Comment: Oh but it cuts off like half of the bar located at index 0 and index 13.  Is there a way to offset so the bar lines up slightly of the Y axis?

Comment: In that case, I think you might need to manually trnasform your data prior to charting.

Answer (score 15):

This will work better :

```
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Comment: This solution was definitely better for me and solved my issue immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You might try `myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.RoundAxisValues()`. It is on by default for the Y axis and I find it generally works better for the X Axis as well.

Answer (score 0):

New Chart().SetYAxis("GPA",0,4);

If You using The chart Class
you could set the Y or X axis using the SetYAxis Method

Comment: How does this work, or more specifically: what is the meaning of the parameters 0 and 4?

Comment: 0 mean the minim and  4 is the maximum they are just a parameters  to the start and end of the Y axis  you could set it also to the X axis and by using the interval property in the them  you could set increment from 0 to 4 how it increase every step

Answer (score 0):

- chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
- chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
- chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -5;
- chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 5;

Comment: //if you are binding chart with datasource like
 chart1.DataSource = ds;
 chart1.DataBind();

//Always do like this
  ds.Tables[0].Columns["X"].DataType = typeof(double);
  ds.Tables[0].Columns["Y"].DataType = typeof(double);

//because by default it will take it as string and X and Y range will not display.