# How to Manipulate X-axis of chart

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, axis-labels

I have made a chart and added the points on runtime. The data is plotted as 

`Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks
Chart1.Series("PH").Points.AddXY(DateTime.Parse(dr.Item("readtime")).ToString("MM-dd"), dr.Item("ph"))`
The data that is plotted holds 7 days of data.
As shown below, the date is repeated.[image]

How to achieve the x axis showing only 11-08, 11-13, 11-14 in this case?

Here is a sample data
[image]

Comment: could you post some of your points ?

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426129/c-sharp-chart-change-max-and-min-values-on-the-x-axis

Comment: edited main post to show sample data

Comment: Carth Tried that but I'm not sure how you can convert datetime format to double which is used in the maximum,minimum. It is also not the solution to this as My current Min,Max is correct.. The issue is with the repeating dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get data from database, use like this,

```
SELECT SUM(ph),SUM(tmp),SUM(orp),SUM(sal),SUM(ec),SUM(tds),SUM(do),readtime
FROM <your tables>
GROUP BY readtime
```

The results set returned from this query is the thing you are looking for....

Comment: Thanks this is an alternative solution but still not an ideal one. The SQL that I use has ORDER BY readtime and I am not allowed to use the SUM function so therefore not allowed to use the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Then read database results into data table or list and using LINQ compute above aggregates and bind them to chart. You must get aggregate, because chart get row by row as x,y values. Hence to get you specifies three columns you have to have only three rows.

Comment: Thanks this gave me inspiration to create my sql in another way that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you show is obviously invalid data.

You have several zero readings occurring at exactly the same time - midnight.

I suspect *these are not even real readings.*

You need to exclude them (and you should probably find out why this is happening - maybe a parsing error?)